# Why is req.params.filmId or more generally req.params.name an unresolved variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, schema

I'm having an issue with req.params. I'm aware of the difference between req.body and req.params, specifically that req.params is for route parameters. In my code below (snippet A) the parameter I would like to access is the :filmId value. However i'm getting a message saying unresolved variable and it is not working for me, I'm not able to access the filmId parameter.

From all I can tell i'm using req.params.filmId correctly, but maybe it has to do with where i'm putting code in the two different router.post blocks I have, I have a router.post to the root path / in my films.js (snippet B) route file but I also have a router.post to the /:filmId path. See (snippet C.1 & C.2) for the to different router.post options, I'm having the issue when I use the code block in either location. Does the router.post and router.get need to be in a specific order? Thanks for the help in advance.

Snippet A.1

```
router.get("/", function(req, res, next) {
    Film.find()
        .exec()
        .then(docs => {
            console.log(docs); 
            res.status(200).json(docs);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).json({error: err});
        });
});
```

Snippet A.2

```
router.get("/:filmId", function(req, res, next) {
    const id = req.params.filmId;
    Film.findById(id)
        .exec()
        .then(doc => {
            console.log(doc);
            res.status(200).json(doc);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).json({error: err});
        });
});
```

Snippet B

This is my film.js model

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const filmSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    _id : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    filmTitle: {type: String, required: true},
    filmRating: {type: Number, required: true}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Film", filmSchema);
```

Snippet C.1

```
 router.post("/", function (req,res,next){
    const film = new Film({
        _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        filmTitle: req.body.filmTitle,
        filmRating: req.body.filmRating
    });
    film
        .save()
        .then(result => {
            console.log(result);
            res.status(201).json({
                message: "Handling POST requests to /films",
                film: film
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).json({
                error: err
            });
        });
});
```

Snippet C.2

```
router.post("/:filmId", function (req,res,next){
const film = new Film({
    _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
    filmTitle: req.body.filmTitle,
    filmRating: req.body.filmRating
});
film
    .save()
    .then(result => {
        console.log(result);
        res.status(201).json({
            message: "Handling POST requests to /films",
            film: film
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({
            error: err
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: How are you calling the `POST` endpoint? Also you do not need to specify `_id : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,` for your schema nor do `_id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),` in the `POST` handler, mongoose adds `_id` automatically for you for both your model as well as when you create a `Film`. Also you should probably only do `res.json` in `then()/catch()` to ensure that you are sending a response only once the save is successful or has failed. Regarding `router.post("/:filmId"`, how would you know a `filmId` for a film that has not been created, how would that be called via HTTP?

Comment: Hey @AlexanderStaroselsky, thank you for the response, I changed the res.json to be in the then()/catch() as I was typing up the question but forgot to switch it in my question, I've made the edit in the original post. I'm new to programming, what do you mean by the POST endpoint? So i can't completely delete the _id: lines from my schema and post handler? I have already created films with postman to add to the database, so I figured it would be able to call upon those already created? I wasn't sure exactly how to build what I'm trying to accomplish, what is the best what to handle it then?

Comment: If you don't include an `_id` when creating a new `Film`, when you successfully `save()`, you will see that an `_id` has been created/added to the `film`. At a base level you can `res.status(201).json(film)` inside the `then()` and `res.status(someErrorCode).json(someErrorObject)` in the `catch()`. What I mean about the `router.post("/:filmId"` is that is probably "wrong" as your client calling the API doesn't know the id of the film when they are calling a POST, as they are asking to create a brand new film. Probably just `router.post("/",` would be enough.

Comment: For troubleshooting, I'd recommend show how you are making the GET request to `router.get('/:filmId'` from your client.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky , right okay I understand the automatic `_id` generation after successfully running `save()`  , I understand that  `router.post("/:filmId"` doesn't logically make sense since I can't post to a location that hasn't been generated yet!, when I was successfully using postman to test these I was getting successful post requests to create a new film with Snippet C.1 or `router.post("/",` I believe I've shown how I am making my `router.get('/:filmId'` request in Snippet A.1 above. Do you need more information besides that? I added my `router.get("/",` request as Snippet A.2